# ICMP time exceeded in-transit

Tags: firewall, freebsd, icmp, ddos

In the last few days my server suffers an attack of this kind:
(bandwith > 60MBit/s, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX are multiple IPs)

```
    tcpdump -n proto ICMP    
    17:15:19.267464 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
    17:15:19.325217 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
    17:15:19.345561 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 56
    17:15:19.484865 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
    17:15:19.529616 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
    17:15:19.957058 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY tcp port 39692 unreachable, length 36
    17:15:19.968957 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP host YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY unreachable, length 56
    17:15:20.112520 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP host YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY unreachable, length 56
    17:15:20.203199 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP host YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY unreachable, length 36
    17:15:20.204803 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > my_ip: ICMP host YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY unreachable, length 36
```

I've FreeBSD 9.1 and my pf.conf is

```
ext_if="em0"
table <blockedips> persist file "/etc/pf-blocked-ips.conf"

set skip on lo0

block drop in log (all) quick on $ext_if from <blockedips> to any

block in
pass out flags S/SA keep state

pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to port 80 flags S/SA keep state
pass in on $ext_if proto tcp to port ssh flags S/SA synproxy state
```

There's anything that i can do with pf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be receiving some backscatter from a ddos attack (http://blog.usu.edu/security/2010/08/24/backscatters-the-name-dos-the-game/).

There's not much you can do about this unless you can filter them in a switch before they hit your server; they're already getting dropped in the kernel as a network anomaly.